# get error when extracting feature of one Chinese sentense using sklearn

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I want to extract feature of a sentence in Chinese using a limited vocabulary,but I get no feature for Chinese word,only get feature for a '2015',it's quite confusing.

this is my code

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-  

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

#load dictionary
dic_file = open("/home/xcy/graduation-design/YangBen/dict.txt")
pn_dict = [ line.strip()for line in dic_file]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(), vocabulary=pn_dict, binary=True)

#load training data
train_file = open("/home/xcy/graduation-design/YangBen/1k.txt")
train_sentence = [ line.strip()  for line in train_file  if line.strip() != "" ]

X = vectorizer.transform(train_sentence)

print(X.toarray())

#print(train_sentence[0].split()[0])

#print(vectorizer.vocabulary_.get('下降'))

#for i in vectorizer.get_feature_names():
#       print(i)
```

/home/xcy/graduation-design/YangBen/dict.txt

```
下降
公司
2015
```

/home/xcy/graduation-design/YangBen/1k.txt

```
2015 年 三 季度 报 发现 ， 虽然 华策 影视 等 公司 的 净利润 同比 有所 下降
```

the output of my code is

```
[[0 0 1]]
```

while following output is expected, the first '1' for '下降' , second '1' for '公司'

```
[[1 1 1]]
```

all three files above is utf-8, watched in vim (:set fileencoding)

Env:

Ubuntu16.04,

Python 2.7.12,

virtualenv 15.1.0,

just installed scikit-learn(pip install -U scikit-learn
) yeserday

Comment: I suspect a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Byte Order Mark) to be at the begining of your first file. Also, you should decode your `line`s from `utf8`.

Comment: @Tnerual  Thank you! I have solved it according your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, you may want to decode your line from `utf8` replacing lines

```
pn_dict = [ line.strip()for line in dic_file]
[...]
train_sentence = [ line.strip()\
                   for line in train_file if line.strip() != "" ]
```

for

```
ENC = 'utf8'
pn_dict = [line.decode(ENC).strip()\
           for line in dic_file]
[...]
train_sentence = [line.decode(ENC).strip()\
                  for line in train_file if line.strip() != "" ]
pn_dict = [line.decode(enc).strip()\
           for line in dic_file]
```

Which should make `print(X.toarray())` return `[[0 1 1]]`

And since I suspect a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to be at the beginning of the file `"dict.txt"`
You may also remove it, doing

```
BOM = u'\ufeff'
[...]
pn_dict[0] = pn_dict[0].replace(BOM,'')
```

And for robustness, you should also do as well for the other file, as follows

```
train_sentence[0] = train_sentence[0].replace(BOM,'')
```

Comment: You are so experienced!